# Rails gem for thin user notice system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, notice

I'm searching for a solution for thin notice system. I found PublicActivity, pfeed and etc. but still not sure that is the best way to solve my problem.

I have a model User and Post, Photo, Video, Comment, Vote. Each model has owner - User. I want to do that: when anybody comment/vote Post|Photo|Video special notice shoud tell about this to the owner like this:
1. User Jack voted for your Video (link_to Video)
2. User Floyd commented your Post (link_to Post)
3. User Julia reply to your Comment (link_to Comment)

What the gem more appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've explored a few gems I say before and found out that PublicActivity is enough to do all I want. I think it's the better gem for this purposes.